# Can I get class in the same way as I can get %s?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Can I get class in the same way as I can get %s? Is this possible? I want to access class with the help of the string. Examples below show what I have in mind.

string example

```
name = raw_input("who are you?")
print "hello %s" % (name,)
```

class example

```
class Temp:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.n = name

testclass = Temp("this is placeholder class")

classname = "testclass"
print %c.n % (classname)
```

Expeted output:
"this is placeholder class"
like in:

```
print testclass.n
```

EDIT: More detailed infromation of what I want to do:
In function instead of writing every possible combination of variables I'd like to do one code that adjusts to query. Example with string

```
name1 = "John"
name2 = "Doe"

inpt = raw_input()

inpt

name = "name%s" % str(inpt)

print "Hi %s" % (name)
```

Outcome hear will be name1 or name2 depending on which number I type in raw_input but instead of that I'd like to have outcome John or Doe depending on which number I type in but not with the string but class. And I don't have to input but I want filename in string to become variable name that will give me output depending on what is contained in asked class subclass (in example above .n). I hope I didn't make this even more confusing.

Comment: What is `%c.n`? What is the expected output?

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking here. Do you mean you want to control how an instance is formatted as a string? If so, you need to give your class a `__str__` method.

Comment: Otherwise, you need to look at [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which gives you access to attributes in the string template: `'{c.n}'.format(c=testclass)`. I don't know what the indirection with `classname` is about though.

Comment: `eval` in python is a function that can interpret string as code.
```` 
classname = "testclass"
print eval("%s.n" (classname))
````

Comment: I think it's possible that @Bardia Heydari gives me answer I look for but I'd like to see example if possible

Comment: Don't store the values in separate variables; store them in a list `names = ["John", "Doe"]`, then use `int(inpt)` to index the list: `name =names[int(inpt)]`.

Comment: That's very useful tip @chepner ! Thanks.

Comment: There's also no need for a format specifier other than `%s` here: `print "%s" % ( testclass.n, )`

Comment: @chepner This is exactly the anwer I was looking for. I feel stupid that I didn't try to do this. I overcomplicated this. Thank you. One more question is this comma necessary?

Comment: It's mostly good practice. If `testclass.n` itself were a tuple with more than one value, `print "%s" % testclass.n` would produce an error because you specifed more values than there were formats. Using `print "%s" % (testclass.n, )` guarantees that only one value is provided to the format operation.

Comment: There is long comment discusion in thread because question was on hold for quite long.